# Disable Camera Snapshot after calling Camera.takePicture Android

Tags: android, camera, preview, android-camera

I am calling takePicture() on my camera object while showing a preview of what is being taken using a surfaceView. I want to be able to call takePicture() without the preview screen freezing with a snapshot of what has just been taken. How can I disable this and keep the preview running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to call takePicture() without the preview screen freezing with a snapshot of what has just been taken. How can I disable this and keep the preview running in the background?

You don't. While the device is reading the data off the CCD and converting into JPEG, the `SurfaceView` preview is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I restart the preview again as quickly as possible after capturing an image? I am trying to give the user an option to save the image while still having the preview running in the background, I have it running OK by saving the previewFrame but the image quality is not the best and feel taking the image from the camera directly would be better. Any opinions will be appreciated.

Comment: @SamRowley: "How can I restart the preview again as quickly as possible after capturing an image?" -- in `onPictureTaken()` of your callback, call `startPreview()`. Here is a project demonstrating saving the image while the preview has been restarted, through an `AsyncTask`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture

Answer (score 0):

```
(new AsyncTask<byte[], String, String>() {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
                    savePictureToSDCard(params[0]);
                    return null;
                }
            }).execute(imageData);
```